# Crystal Reports 2013: Filter shown records

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report with the following structure:

```
<sales person>
  <appointment date>
  <appointment status>
```

Now, the appointment status can be either 'kept', 'cancelled by customer', or 'cancelled by sales person' (for simplicity).  I want to calculate the percentage that were cancelled.  To calculate that, I will need to select all of the appointments, and divide the number that was not kept by the total number.  Okay, I get that.

Now, the trouble is that I also want to show the appointments that were cancelled in my report, and exclude the appointments that were kept.  In other words, I pretty much just want to skip printing these irrelevant records.  How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

formula1

```
If {<appointment status>} = "kept" then 1 else 0
```

That will give you a count which you can use to get your percentage for sales person.

```
   if sum({@formula1},{<sales person>}) > 0 
    then sum({@formula1},{<sales person>}) % count({<appointment status>} ,{<sales person>})
    else 0
```

Then suppress the details with a formula like this

```
{@formula1} = 1
```